# Spring Roo - many to many relationship deletes and inserting at every update- How to change this behavior

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-roo

I have two entities created. 
Entity BOOK, Entity AUTHOR having many to many relationship.
In the db I got tables [book,author, book_author].
Table book_author maps the many to many relationship.

When I update authors of a book all related relationship records in book_author 
get deleted and then get re-inserted. 
**Is there a way to alter this behavior to do updates as necessary, without doing 
delete and re-insert.**

By the no modification have been done manually. All the code have been done with ROO.

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behavior if "List" is used as the collection to keep relationship 
in the entity level. Instead we can use a "Set" which will make updates and deletes as 
necessary without doing delete and re-insert.

This is clearly explained in the following article.
http://assarconsulting.blogspot.com/2009/08/why-hibernate-does-delete-all-then-re.html